# What should I do to make (name).move be the (name)?

Tags: python

```
class Point:
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.__x = x
    self.__y = y

def x(self, x):
    self.__x = x

def y(self, y):
    self.__y = y

def move(self, dx, dy):
    self.__x += dx
    self.__y += dy
    return Point(self.__x, self.__y)
    
def __str__(self):
    return "(%d, %d)" %(self.__x, self.__y)

def main() :
    a = Point()
    b = Point(1,5)
    print("a =",a)
    a.move(2,3)
    b.move(4,3).move(-1,-2)
    print("a =",a," B =",b)

main()
```

I want to get the answer a=(2, 3), b=(4, 6) but when I try to debug, b.move only works once.
I think I should get b.move =b so that to change the b itself, not Point(self.__x, self.__y).
Instead of writing return Point(self.__x, self.__y), what should I write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to define the move method this way:

```
    def move(self, dx, dy):
        self.__x += dx
        self.__y += dy
        return self
```

Comment: Really appreciating for your quick answer!! This is a really simple solution but I can't do anything. I should study more about the definition and base of 'Class'. Anyway, really big thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change your class up a bit like the following

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%d, %d)" %(self.__x, self.__y)

    def move(self,xVal,yVal):
        def x(xVal):
            self.__x += xVal

        def y(yVal):
            self.__y += yVal
            return self.__y
        return (x(xVal),y(yVal))
            

        

def main() :
    a = Point()
    b = Point(1,5)
    print("a =",a)
    a.move(2,3)
    b.move(4,3)
    print("a =",a," B =",b)

main()
```

output

```
a = (0, 0)
a = (2, 3)  B = (5, 8)
```

Now move calls x and y by its self. You just pass in x and y to `.move()`

Comment: Really appreciating for your quick answer!! This could be another solution. But first I think I need to study more about 'Class'. Anyway, really big thanks again!

Comment: If this answered your question it would be lovely if you accept the answer. Also if you appreciated my time go ahead and upvote. Up to you! Glad to be of help anyways!